# Parsing string in SQL Server 2008 R2 or vb6.0

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, vb6

Help me : I have a string

```
Colour - red / blue / yellow / navy
```

How do I make a looping parsing string so it can be

```
Colour red
Colour blue
Colour yellow
Colour navy
Red blue
Red yellow
Red navy
Blue yellow
Blue navy
Yellow navy
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Code Below

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 'Colour - red / blue / yellow / navy'
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @s = @s + '/' , @output = '';

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 1 pos

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pos + 1  FROM cte1   WHERE pos < len(@s)
    )
    ,cte2 AS (
        SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY pos) Id,pos FROM cte1 WHERE Substring(@s, pos, 1) IN ('-','/')
    )
    ,cte3 AS (
        SELECT a.Id, Rtrim(LTrim(SubString(@s, isNull(b.pos, 0) + 1, a.pos - isNull(b.pos, 1) - 1))) word  FROM cte2 a
            LEFT JOIN cte2 b ON a.Id - 1 = b.Id
    )
SELECT @output = @output + ' ' + a.word + ' ' + b.word FROM cte3 a
        INNER JOIN cte3 b ON a.Id < b.Id
        ORDER BY a.Id

SELECT @output
```